# Move tags section out of the tabs in Magento?

Tags: magento

On [this page](http://www.princessly.com/a-line-strapless-sleeveless-sweep-train-fish-scale-wedding-dress.html), I'm trying to move the tags (list of tags and tags form) out of the tabs to the open area immediately before the Reviews section.

I copied everything from the /template/tag/list.phtml to /template/catalog/product/view.phtml:

```
<div class="box-collateral box-tags">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Product Tags') ?></h2>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('list_before')?>
    <?php if( $this->getCount() ): ?>
    <h3><?php echo $this->__('Other people marked this product with these tags:') ?></h3>
    <ul id="<?php echo $this->getUniqueHtmlId('product-tags_'); ?>" class="product-tags">
        <?php echo $this->renderTags('<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a> (%3$s)</li>') ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        decorateGeneric($("<?php echo $this->getUniqueHtmlId('product-tags_'); ?>").select('li'), ['first', 'last']);
    </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form id="addTagForm" action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" method="get">
        <div class="form-add">
            <label for="productTagName"><?php echo $this->__('Add Your Tags:') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" name="productTagName" id="productTagName" />
            </div>
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add Tags') ?>" class="button" onclick="submitTagForm()">
                <span>
                    <span><?php echo $this->__('Add Tags') ?></span>
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p class="note"><?php echo $this->__("Use spaces to separate tags. Use single quotes (') for phrases.") ?></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var addTagFormJs = new VarienForm('addTagForm');
        function submitTagForm(){
            if(addTagFormJs.validator.validate()) {
                addTagFormJs.form.submit();
            }
        }
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

While the form is correctly showing, the tags are not.

I guess it's something to do with the "$this->getCount()". So how can I get $this for tags in view.phtml? Or how can I make this work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it cannot work if you copied code from template tag/list.phtml to catalog/product/view.phtml because behind of catalog/product/view.phtml is a block which doesnt support same set of methods as block behind tag/list.phtml.

I suggest to move tag_list block inside of product_view block in layout XML. And then in catalog/product/view.phtml you can use something like

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tag_list'); ?>
```

which would print content of tag/list.phtml.

Or if you dont want to move block in layout xmls then you can use something like

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('tag_list')->toHtml(); ?>
```

but it's not so nice and clean :) I suggest to go with option one. Some resources how to work with layout is available in Magento Commerce site.